# Windows XP - why is my usbaudio.sys in capitals?

Tags: windows-xp, midi, usb-audio

I'm trying to diagnose a problem with a USB MIDI input device not working on WindowsXP.

I've noticed that my usbaudio.sys In /Windows/System32/Drivers/ is actually named USBAUDIO.sys.  My question is - why the capitals?  Other drivers are not named like this.

What options do I have for restoring this driver in case its bad? (I don't have a system restore point unfortunately).

Thank you

Comment: Given that MIDI isn't an audio format, but a control format, is it not possible that you're looking at the wrong driver. What does the Device Manager have to say about your MIDI device? As to why they created the file name in all caps, that's just because they did. :)

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm aware that it's not audio data, but from what I can gather from google, it seems that MIDI over USB might be one of its responsibilities.  Another reason I was suspicious of the caps is that I've seen the file on the web, not in caps.

Comment: Device manager sees two things - A USB Audio Device (which might actually be the soundcard element of the controller), and a USB Composite device (which may turn out to be the midi controller).  Unfortunately Tools like MIDI-OX don't see any midi devices.

Comment: What's the device that you're connecting to your computer. It may be relevant.

Comment: It's this: http://www.mixvibes.com/content/products/u-mix-control-pro-2 There are two parts really: a USB soundcard, and a USB MIDI Input device, it's the latter that's not being recognised.

Comment: Some more background info - they don't list XP compatibility in the marketing, but I've confirmed with the manufacturer that midi control will work with XP.  Secondly they pointed me in the direction of some other posts where windows USB MIDI had been messed up by logitec webcam installations.  I did have a logitec webcam, but the software and drivers have been uninstalled.

Comment: Note that in Windows file names, case is ignored (although preserved). `USBAUDIO.sys` and `usbaudio.sys` refer to the same file. The reason for upper-case name might be that the file was copied from an 8.3-only filesystem. Or it might be not. Who knows.

Comment: I saw the WebCam stuff. I saw a post that claimed you had to use the same USB socket that you first installed with(?!) I also read some stuff regarding a Korg VFX driver. I don't know if that's relevant to your device though. I've been in a world of hurt before, especially with ProTools and some other MIDI fun, so I know how frustrating it can be. Is a complete Windows XP reinstall doable? Painful I know, but sometimes the problem is buried in 1,000s of lines of registry! :(

Comment: @grawity - yeah, I guess it's probably not relevant, but I thought I'd ask :)

Comment: @IanAtkin - Right, I'll search for the Korg issues too, thanks (I guess it's probably the same problem, if both devices are using standard drivers).  Yeah, it's starting to look like a clean install might be the best option - oh well!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the driver in question, you may be able to download it (or even a newer version) from the manufacturer's web site.

That said, you have issues with a MIDI device. There are usually two avenues to get MIDI working: 1. the device comes with an installation disc, 2. the MIDI device driver is installed by Windows when it's plugged in.

There are a slew of things that may be causing a conflict. This could be something as simple as a Direct-X conflict, to another device that you've installed recently.

Windows XP also had a bug at one time whereby USB controllers may be set to switch off power as a power saving mechanism:

In the Device Manager...

1. Double click "Universal Serial Bus Controllers"
2. Find "USB root hub"
3. Double click the first USB hub
4. In the properties dialog, click the "Power Managemen" tab
5. Uncheck "Allow computer to turn off this device to save power"

The Logitech WebCam issue requires a registry edit. A simple uninstall doesn't fix the conflict...

1. Start regedit
2. Go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Class\{4D36E96C-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` and delete `LowerFilters` and `UpperFilters`
3. Go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Class\{6BDD1FC6-810F-11DO-BEC7-08002BE2092F}` and delete `LowerFilters`
4. Go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Class\{6BDD1FC5-810F-11DO-BEC7-08002BE2092F}` and delete `UpperFilters`
5. Move back to the root of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Class\`
6. Search for `LVUSBSTA`. For any place found (only in `Control\Class`), delete the `LowerFilters` item (it is the item that contain the value `LVUSBSTA` found)
7. Restart the computer

Comment: Thanks Ian.  I've got the manufacturer's drivers installed (tried a couple of times) (although for the MIDI component they are just using the standard windows MIDI over USB apparently).  I've also already unchecked all of the USB-Root-hub power-management options in device-manager (sorry should have mentioned that)

Comment: The Direct-X conflict is something that I haven't investigated - do you know how I might go about that?

Comment: Basically, the claim was that Direct-X 9 conflicted with some MIDI drivers. The solution was to remove it or roll back to an earlier version.

Comment: Looks like I've got DX 9c.  Thanks, something else to try then. Although I'm surprised that more people aren't seeing the problem if its that.

Comment: Also see my edit regarding the Logitech issue. I don't know if you did this or if you just uninstalled the driver.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I saw those but unfortunately I don't have any of those fields for those keys :(

Answer (score 1):

I looked in my system folder and the ALLCAPS dlls usually have names in the 8.3 format (8 letter name, 3 letter extension), which means that they are from the DOS era. I suspect this is a leftover naming convention from then.

Comment: Thanks Jikag - Weird though, as I'm sure there was no Audio-over-USB in DOS days!

Comment: @UpTheCreek Actually, there were aplenty. MIDI was created in the mid-80s, so it's been around for quite some time.

Comment: @IanAtkin, sure MIDI is ancient, but USB only became popular in the late 90s and midi-over-usb in the last 10 years

Comment: Yeah, I had a MIDISport USB adapter on Windows 2000 in 1998. Sometimes, it even worked! :)